# Convert large number of cameras to vertices with normals

Tags: particles, camera, vertices, photogrammetry

I'm using Agisoft Metashape to create 3D models for Blender and I want to render some images in Blender that also show where the photographs were taken, with a little camera object at each location. I want to use the camera positions for a 'hair' physics object so that a model of the camera will appear at each position.

It is possible to export the camera positions from Metashape as a 3D file in the same coordinate system as the model so in theory this should be easy. But it ain't.

The problem is to do with orientations. I've tried all the export formats that can go straight into Blender (abc, xml, out, chan, txt, rzml, pro, dat, orn, prj, smtxml, fbx) but none of them bring the orientations in correctly. Some of the text export formats include rotation but as quaternion instead of a 3 component vector. However, some of the formats (abc I think) do bring the cameras straight in to Blender with proper orientation except that they are actual Blender cameras! So I can select them individually and render from them but not see them as objects in a render! Gah!

There are hundreds of them - does anyone know an automated way to convert multiple Blender cameras to vertices with normals? I suppose there is a way of python scripting it but I'm too basic for that :-)